# .htaccess rewrite url for seo friendly urls causes 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

Here are some example urls I wish to rewrite:

> ```
> https://website.com?c=food&s=cheese&p=3
> https://website.com?c=food&s=cheese
> https://website.com?s=cheese
> ```

I wish for the above to be rewritten to:

> ```
> https://website.com/food/cheese/3
> https://website.com/food/cheese
> https://website.com/cheese
> ```

Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?c=$1&s=$2&p=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?c=$1&s=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?s=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone see whats going wrong? I a remove the last line

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?s=$1 [L]
```

The page loads however, it seems to be rewriting the css and js files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RewriteCond` is only applicable to the immediate next `RewriteRule`. Since you have multiple rules needing same conditions, it is better to define a separate rule to exclude all files, directories and known URIs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?c=$1&s=$2&p=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?c=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it will be failing/causing a server error is because it is placed in infinite recursion - `^([^/]*)$` redirects to `/?s=$1` which is picked up again by `^([^/]*)$`, repeat ad infinitum.

Try this instead. It's not necessarily the best rewrite rule but it should fix your specific problem:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]`